# How change icon size in Button.Image Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How I can change size icon? I want to enlarge because the icon is too small. In the original the icon has a correct size but in the application is too small

```
    <StackLayout>
        <local:AnimatedButton BackgroundColor="#ffffff" 
                        BorderColor="#ffffff" 
                        BorderRadius="25" 
                        WidthRequest="50" 
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        Command="{Binding CenterMyLocationCommand}">
            <Button.Image>
                <FileImageSource File="googlemap_view_center_button.png" />
            </Button.Image>
        </local:AnimatedButton> 
    </StackLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to add/change WidthRequest and HeightRequest (also check: Width and Height) attributes